# Move resources/volumes across contexts in Kubernetes clusters

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kops, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have a kubernetss cluster which i have started with a context "dev1.k8s.local" and it has a stateful set with EBS -PV(Persistent volumes)
now we are planning to start another context "dev2.k8s.local"
is there a way i can move dev1 context EBS volumes to context "dev2.k8s.local"

```
i am using K8S 1.10 & KOPS 1.10 Version
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Context is simply a representation of a Kubernetes configuration, typically `~/.kube/config`. This file can have [multiple configurations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) in it that are managed manually or with `kubectl context`.

When you provision a second Kubernetes cluster on AWS using Kops, brand new resources are recreated that have no frame of reference about the other cluster. Your EBS volumes that were created for PVs in your original cluster cannot simply be transferred between clusters using a context entry in your configuration file. That's not how it is designed to work.

Aside from the design problem, there is also a serious technical hurdle involved. EBS volumes are [ReadWriteOnce](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes). Meaning that they can only be attached to a single pod at once. The reason this constraint exists is because the EBS connection is block storage that is treated like a physical block device connected to the underlying worker node running your pod. That physical block device does not exist on the worker nodes in your other cluster. So it's impossible to simply move the pointer over.

The best way to accomplish this would be to back up and copy over the disk. How you handle this is up to your team. One way you could do it is by mounting both EBS volumes and copying the data over manually. You could also take a snapshot and restore the data to the other volume.